# Python Error: List assignment index out of range when list has more than 1 value

Tags: python, list, range, runtime-error

I am writing code for a card game that I made, and I am trying to add cards to the computer's hand when they can't put one down. The function works completely fine when it has 1 or 0 cards in its hand, but if it has any more, I get Index Error: List assignment index out of range

This is the code that plays during the computer's turn:

```
def calculate():
    global computer_calculate, player_calculate, table_index, hand_index, deck
    table_index = -1
    hand_index = -1
    card_played = False
    played_on = False
    if computer_calculate == True:
        print("These are the computer's cards.\n" + str(computer.table))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("This is the card it has just drawn.\n" + str(computer.hand[-1]))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("These are all of the cards in its hand.\n" + str(computer.hand))
        time.sleep(1)
        for card in computer.hand:
            hand_index += 1
            card.in_play = False
            for table_card in computer.table:
                table_index += 1
                if played_on == False:
                    if (card.value * table_card.value) % 10 == 0:
                        computer.table[table_index] = computer.hand[hand_index]
                        card_played = True
                        card.in_play = True
                        played_on = True
                        print("The computer played their card. They played " + str(card.value) + " on " + str(table_card.value) + " because " + str(card.value) + " multiplied by " + str(table_card.value) + " equals " + str((card.value * table_card.value)) + ", which is a multiple of ten.")
                        time.sleep(3)
                    elif (card.value / table_card.value) % 10 == 0:
                        computer.table[table_index] = computer.hand[hand_index]
                        card_played = True
                        card.in_play = True
                        played_on = True
                        print("The computer played their card. They played " + str(card.value) + " on " + str(table_card.value) + " because " + str(card.value) + " divided by " + str(table_card.value) + " equals " + str((card.value / table_card.value)) + ", which is a multiple of ten.")
                        time.sleep(5)
                    elif (card.value + table_card.value) % 10 == 0:
                        computer.table[table_index] = computer.hand[hand_index]
                        card_played = True
                        card.in_play = True
                        played_on = True
                        print("The computer played their card. They played " + str(card.value) + " on " + str(table_card.value) + " because " + str(card.value) + " added to " + str(table_card.value) + " equals " + str((card.value + table_card.value)) + ", which is a multiple of ten.")
                        time.sleep(5)
                    elif (card.value - table_card.value) % 10 == 0:
                        computer.table[table_index] = computer.hand[hand_index]
                        card_played = True
                        card.in_play = True
                        played_on = True
                        print("The computer played their card. They played " + str(card.value) + " on " + str(table_card.value) + " because the difference of " + str(card.value) + " and " + str(table_card.value) + " equals " + str(abs(card.value - table_card.value)) + ", which is a multiple of ten.")
                        time.sleep(3)
            if card.in_play == True:
                computer.hand.remove(card)
        if card_played == False:
            print("The computer could not find a legal move. The card has been added to its hand.")
```

Wherever it says `computer.table[table_index] = computer.hand[hand_index]`, it gives me the error whenever the computer has 2 or more cards in its hand. Otherwise, everything works perfectly fine. If you need the rest of the code just let me know.

Comment: I think the problem is you initialize `table_index` at the top of the function so you keep incrementing it for every iteration of the outer loop. You probably need to initialize it in the `for card in computer.hand` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two nested for loops: the outer one iterates through the cards in the computer's hand, and the inner one iterates through cards on the table. This means that the inner for loop has to execute multiple times if there are multiple cards in the hand. In order for this to work properly, your `table_index` variable needs to get reset before the inner for loop restarts. One way to accomplish this would be to move the line `table_index = -1` just inside that outer for loop, right before `hand_index += 1`.
However, a cleaner way to do this is to make use of Python's `enumerate()` function, as recommended by Nonlinear. Read about that [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/).It lets you iterate over an iterable (such as a list) and get access to both the index variable and the list element at each iteration without having to initialize or increment the index.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing arises because when looping in `computer.hand`, you are not initializing `table_index`. On  the first iteration, everything works well (this is the reason it works if the computer has 0 or 1 card). But on the second iteration, `table_index` stays on whatever value it was before. To solve your problem, you can either move `table_index = -1` inside the first for loop, or use the python [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/) function, which would make your code a lot cleaner.